# Null Object Reference on TextView in getView()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, adapter, getview

Here is my adapter code; keep in mind for the `ListView` I am returning two types of views.
(`LogCat` under code`)

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
   private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> userItemObjectList) {
      super(context, R.layout.item_row_layout, userItemObjectList);

      inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t6;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos) {
    Item i = getItem(pos);
    String season = i.season;
    if (!season.equals(lastSeason)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (rowType == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_layout, parent,
                    false);

            holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvReviewTotalForItem);
            holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvPercentageItems);
            holder.t6 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvItemRowReviewLabel);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else if (rowType == 1) {

           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_season, parent,
                    false);

            holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seasonNumber);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item i = getItem(position);
    String episode = i.item;
    String rating = i.ratings;
    String review = i.reviews;

    if (rowType == 1) {

        String season = i.season;
        lastSeason = season;
        holder.t2.setText("Season " + lastSeason);

    } else if (rowType == 0) {

        holder.t1.setText(episode); // THIS IS WHERE NULL TEXTVIEW IS FOUND
        holder.t3.setText(review);
        holder.t4.setText(rating);
        holder.t4.setText(rating);

    }


    return convertView;
}
```

}

Here is my `LogCat`:

```
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685): Process: com.---.---, PID: 7685
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at com.---.---.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:181)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5143)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3243)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3587)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3431)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
07-28 09:50:02.689: E/AndroidRuntime(7685):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:548
```

I have confirmed, through logging, that the null `TextView` is in `rowType` 0.  It is null when `convertView is NOT` null (so it happens when it is recycling the views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had once similar problem, i solved it by creating separate ViewHolders for each layout:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ViewHolder2 holder2;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {


        if (rowType == 0) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_layout, parent,
                    false);

            holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvReviewTotalForItem);
            holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvPercentageItems);
            holder.t6 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvItemRowReviewLabel);

            convertView.setTag(holder, R.layout.item_row_layout);

        } else if (rowType == 1) {
           holder2 = new ViewHolder2();
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_season, parent,
                    false);

            holder2.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seasonNumber);

            convertView.setTag(holder, R.layout.row_season);
        }

    } else {
        if (rowType == 0) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.item_row_layout);
        } else if (rowType == 1) {
            holder2 = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag(R.layout.row_season);
        }
    }

    Item i = getItem(position);
    String episode = i.item;
    String rating = i.ratings;
    String review = i.reviews;

    if (rowType == 1) {

        String season = i.season;
        lastSeason = season;
        holder2.t2.setText("Season " + lastSeason);

    } else if (rowType == 0) {

        holder.t1.setText(episode); // THIS IS WHERE NULL TEXTVIEW IS FOUND
        holder.t3.setText(review);
        holder.t4.setText(rating);
        holder.t4.setText(rating);

    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Viewholders:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView t1;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t6;
}

static class ViewHolder2 {
    TextView t2;
}
```

Comment: How can we use same for both convertView.setTag(holder, R.layout.item_row_layout);

Answer (score 0):

You said that the `rowType` is `1` (through the debug) but the null appears inside the `If statement` where the `rowType` is `0` (you have a comment in the first line of that If indicating it).

Comment: Very sorry, that was a typo.  I confirmed it is 0, NOT 1.  (fixed)

Comment: Can you post the two XMLs of your layouts?

Comment: I found out one more thing with logging.  The actual object of `holder` is NOT null.  But the property of `holder.t1` is.

Answer (score 0):

you must have set text to textView before it has been initialise